# How to sort the output of find?

Tags: linux, shell, sorting, pipe

I'm using the find command to list files with their name containing a string:

`find ~/ -type f -name "*inductive*"`

I would like to use a pipe to sort the resulting list of files.  I would like to be able to sort by file size, date created, date accessed ...  How can I do this?
Thanks.

Comment: this question might help: http://superuser.com/questions/416308/how-to-list-files-recursively-and-sort-them-by-modification-time essentially, you put what you want to sort on as the first field by editing the output format, then sort the outputs

Comment: for example: find -type f -printf '%T+\t%p\n' | sort -n

Comment: Sorting by creation date is impossible in Linux because it has no concept of file creation time.

Comment: @geewee The answers to [Birth is empty on ext4](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/50177) offer ways around this issue with "birth time" - The field gets populated (see below) only coreutils stat does not display it. - You can get the creation time via debugfs ... I combined this into a simple shell function ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorting the output by creation time is impossible in Linux (`ctime` is not file creation date). `stat` has the ability to show a file's *birth time* using the `%w` and `%W` format tags, but they always show `-` and `0`, respectively, even on filesystems that store creation time/birth time. Hence, it is practically useless for this purpose on Linux.

The other two sorting orders are possible, though:

```
# Sort by size:
find ~/ -type f -name "*inductive* -exec ls -ltu {} \; | sort -k 5 -n

# Sort by access time:
find ~/ -type f -name "*inductive* -exec ls -ltu {} \; | sort -k 6 -M
```

You can add the `-r` flag to `sort` to reverse the sorting order. See `man sort` for more information.

Depending on the size of `find`'s output, it may take some time for `sort` to produce sorted output.

Comment: The answers to [Birth is empty on ext4](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/50177) offer ways around this issue with "birth time" - The field gets populated (see below) only coreutils stat does not display it. - You can get the creation time via debugfs ... I combined this into a simple shell function ...

Comment: What is the purpose of the {} and the \; in these commands?

Comment: The curly braces are simply part of the syntax. See `man find`. Bash uses semicolon as command separator. The backslash before the semicolon treats the latter as a literal character and tells bash to pass it to `find`, where it's used to mark the end of `-exec`. It's also documented in `man find`.

Comment: by time : `sort -k6M  -k7n`